# Simplify a boolean algebra expression: xy + xz' + x'yz

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I need to simplify `xy + xz' + x'yz` into `xz' + yz`. I know that these expressions are equal in truth value, but I'm not sure how to simplify the first to get the second.

Here are the steps I can do:
1) `xy + xz' + x'yz`
2) `y(x + x'z) + xz'`
3) `y((x + x')(x + z)) + xz'`
4) `y(x + z) + xz'`

But that is where I get stuck. Any help you can give me would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to assume the in-question one; it gets repeated and actually does reduce to the mentioned answer!

Comment: I am so sorry! The one in the question. I have updated the title. It's late here and I've been working on this project for too long :)

Comment: Since you don't want $xy$, split  $xy$ as $xy(z+z')$ and try to group terms

Comment: $x=1,y=1,z=0$: then $xy+xz'+x'yz=1+1+0=0$ and $xz'+yz=1+0=1$. These terms are not equal.

Comment: @miracle173, $1+1+0=1$.  This is boolean algebra, not binary arithmetic.

Comment: What @JoelReyesNoche said.

Comment: thx, now I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xy+xz'+x'yz$
$=(xyz+xyz')+(xyz'+xy'z')+x'yz$
$=xyz+(xyz'+xy'z')+x'yz$
$=xyz+xz'+x'yz$
$=(x+x')yz+xz'$
$=xz'+yz$

Comment: Can you explain how `(xyz' + xy'z')` evaluates to `xz'`?

Comment: $xyz'+xy'z'=xz'(y+y')=xz'$